# REST API: Best way to do/undo an action on a resource

Tags: rest, api-design

*Note: I consider here that `POST` means "create" and `PUT` means "update", as GitHub does. This is not the place to argument in favor of `POST` or `PUT`.*

I have a `company` resource and an `assign` action. I'm wondering how to translate this behavior in my REST API.

I thought about something like:

```
PUT /company/:id/assign
user_id: 5
```

What about if I want to **unassign** this user?

- Should I use a boolean as a parameter?
- Should I use an `unassign` action?
- Should I use use another HTTP verb?

On the latest GitHub API I saw how to [star a gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#star-a-gist):

```
PUT /gists/:id/star
```

Why not, but how to [unstar a gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#unstar-a-gist):

```
DELETE /gists/:id/star
```

It seems pretty strange to me. You are **updating** an action on a resource and **deleting** it. Weird. I could understand whether `POST` instead of `PUT`.

`POST /gists/:id/star` and `DELETE /gists/:id/star` seems more logic to me. What do you think?

**EDIT:** I'm going to work with `POST` and `DELETE`. But as this is not possible to send data with the `DELETE` method, I have to pass the `user_id` in URL:

```
POST /company/:id/assign/:user_id
DELETE /company/:id/assign/:user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a boolean is not really clear. I could consider it as a non-obvious argument term. Consider that the most the API interpretation is obvious, the most your syntax is good.

Using the DELETE method is, finally, the best option you can choose. When you assign a user to a company, you create a relation. When you want to unassign, you delete the relation.

Comment: +1, `POST /assignments {user: id, company: id} -> 201 id` that's all. Assign is an operation name, and not a resource name...